# Forecast 5-7 Day Sales

Tags: forecasting, arima

I have daily sales data between 2013-02-18 to 2017-02-12 that has only 4 days of data missing (all the Xmases on the 25th of each year). These holidays have a sale volume of zero. **My purpose is to understand how to staff my store for the upcoming week by short-term predicting my sales for the next 5-7 days worth of data.**

I start by setting up this data as a time series:

```
ts <- ts(mydata, frequency = 365)
```

and then an initial analysis through a decomposition:

[image: Decomposition of daily data between 2013-02-18 to 2017-02-12]

This seems to show I have a declining sales trend, but there is some seasonality, if I'm not mistaken. So, to start my forecast implementation, I  fit an arima model for the first two years worth of data by doing:

```
#Updated to use Chris Haug's suggestion of the window function
wts <- window(ts, start = c(1,730), frequency = 365)
fit <- auto.arima(wts, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE)

Series: wts 
ARIMA(4,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3      ar4      ma1
      0.2616  -0.2922  -0.1305  -0.3070  -0.8833
s.e.  0.0400   0.0370   0.0370   0.0385   0.0257

sigma^2 estimated as 10067601:  log likelihood=-6903.86
AIC=13819.73   AICc=13819.85   BIC=13847.27
```

This model doesn't seem right to me, because it does not include any seasonality. I know I have enough data. Rob Hyndman's blog said to try using `ets` which also showed no seasonality. What am I not understanding about this data series or the forecasting methodology?

**UPDATE 07-31-2017**
At @ChrisHaug 's suggestion, I leveraged a tbats model for my data.

```
# forecast using tbats
y <- msts(wts, seasonal.periods = c(7, 365))       # creating a multi-seasonal time series
fit_tbats <- tbats(y)
fc <- forecast(fit_tbats,h=90)
plot(fc)
```

[image]

Particular characteristics of this model that seem pertinent to me are seasonal parameters (which correspond), though I'm not sure how to interpret the F-terms. The ARMA model is a surprise to me as I would've atleast expected AR of 1 or higher.

```
TBATS(1, {0,0}, 0.997, {<7,2>, <365,5>})
...
...
Sigma: 2748.952
AIC: 16490.93

## ignore, as next line is reference interpretation for myself follows
# TBATS({box-cox param}, {ARMA(p,q)}, {damping}, <seasonal periods, F-terms>)
```

Additionally, I've added the auto-correlation plots for the first 365 days of data. I see high correlation on the 7th lag which seems to be expressed by weekly seasonality.

[image]

I'm continuing to read through Dr. Hyndman's [paper](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/ComplexSeasonality.pdf) but I'm open to more ideas on tuning this model.

Comment: Make sure you pass in a `ts` object which has its frequency correctly set, or else typically no seasonal models will be attempted at all. In this specific case, the object you call `ts` is indeed of class `ts`, but `ts[1:730]` is actually a vector (`numeric`), and has no frequency. If you want to slice a `ts` and keep its timeseries properties, use the `window` function instead.

Comment: @ChrisHaug I've updated it to use the window function to subset the time series, but I don' think it made a difference. I've also called `class(wts)` to ensure this is a timeseries object.

Comment: Ok, then `auto.arima` should presumably try models with effects at lag 365, but this may not be supported by the data. Actually, I would perhaps expect more something like a combination of weekly and monthly seasonality. Have you looked at `forecast::tbats`? It's similar to `forecast::ets` but also allows for multiple seasonalities.

Comment: Seems like this might be a way to go. i will experiment with tbats. it seems to make sense that there are two seasonalities here, I think. Folks could come in and make buy more on weekends, while the weather could also affect how many people make it into the store. I will try this and modify my post in the coming days.